# constructor for SpriteBatch explained

Tags: libgdx, spritebatch

This is a definition of SpriteBatch constructor from docs:

```
SpriteBatch()
Constructs a new SpriteBatch with a size of 1000, one buffer, and the default shader.
```

Buffer is like temporary storage for data that needs to be set on screen. So one buffer means one piece of memory in RAM? The size parameter is the number of bytes in this piece of memory?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "piece of memory". The size is the number of sprites that can be drawn with one GPU draw call. The buffer is this size times about 80 bytes.